# Pin specific range of data to specific node in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new for Cassandra development. I have total 5 million of rows and 4 nodes.
I have to save first million records to Node A, next million records to Node B, next 1.5 million records to Node C and 1.5 million records to Node D.

I have read Random partition and Ordered Partition.

My partition key is numeric.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: please don't use Indian worlds like "Lakh" here.

Comment: @user8324594 It's a very uncommon use case for Cassandra, we need to understand a bit more what is the goal here. A few questions to help us:

(1) What replication factor do you plan to use? From your question, it sounds like you plan to use RF=1.


(2) Why do you want to pin some data to some specific nodes? Cassandra has not really be designed for this use case (you can manage to achieve that if necessary)

(3) What do you mean by "I have read Random partition and Ordered Partition"

Comment: Ans 1) Replication factor is 2 .
Ans 2) We have 15 million data and we have to insert within few seconds
Ans 3) I have read RP and OP just to get idea for my case is it possible also I found OP is not recommended. Can any one guide me for the same?